# Purchase vs. Order

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

What is the difference in meaning between `Purchase` and `Order`?

Is there a preference for `Purchase` vs. `Order` in some cases/regions/dialects etc.

Specifically in e-shops, when should we use `purchase` and when `order`?

When should we use them as a verb, and when as a noun?

Comment: This is a general reference question. Please check a good online dictionary. A good starting point is http://OneLook.com.

Comment: @MετάEd, I don't think a dictionary would give me such explanations and use cases as much as these good answers I've got here. OneLook.com did not provide me with even good enough definitions.

Comment: Relevant definitions from the top OneLook result: *purchase* (v): **buy**; *purchase* (n) **the act of buying**. *order* (v): **request to be supplied with**; *order* (n) **a commission or instruction to buy, sell, or supply something**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Purchase* means to buy or acquire something. If you walk down the street, pop into your local BestBuy store and buy a computer, you can say that you purchased a computer. *Order* means that you request, book or reserve something. In some cases you wouldn't be charged for the item until it's been shipped to you. In AmE, I can't speak for BrE, if you buy something online, you place an order for it. You could very well say *you purchased something from Amazon*, but that wouldn't be that common as the other one.

That said, in todays online world, the two would seem interchangeable and wouldn't make a big difference unless you were an orthodox.

Answer (score 5):

In US usage they can have different meanings. In connection with commercial transactions, [*order*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/order?q=order) means

> [with object] request (something) to be made, supplied, or served: *my friend ordered the tickets last week*

This may or may not indicate a completed transaction. Sometimes you want to consider a *purchase* and the goods are not in stock.  The shop might *order* the product so that it is available for you to consider at a later date. Even the shop may not be *purchasing* the goods since they may be on consignment.

[*Purchase*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/purchase?q=purchase) is a completion of a transaction

> acquire (something) by paying for it; buy:

At times, the placing of an *order* may invovle a *purchase*, but that depends on the circumstances of the relationship.

The noun forms of each verb have comparable meanings and the choice of word form is a question of style.

Comment: If I could I would accept both yours and Noah's answers. I would accept his because of the more votes.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you would not use *order* as a verb if you walked through a store, selected items from the shelf, and took them to a cash register to pay. The verb *order* is used when a customer requests something for purchase (e.g., we can *order* a book from Amazon, or *order* a meal at a restaurant). However, *order* can be (and is) used as a noun in the point-of-sale environment. For example, a supervisor might say to a cashier:

> When you're done with that order, close your register, and go help Tom in the back.

For some reason, *purchase a book on Amazon* sounds find to me, but *purchase a meal at a restaurant* sounds decidedly less familiar than *order a meal at a restaurant*, although I'd hardly call *purchase* inaccurate or ungrammatical in that context.

Comment: I think it's because a meal doesn't last long, whereas "purchase" seems to have a connotation of "property" which implies you purchased something that is going to last long. You usually don't consider meal as something you own since whether it did or not will become irrelevant a few minutes/hours after purchase. But I don't have sources for this, just a possible explanation.

Answer (score 3):

While it is true that, because of the (so to speak) mechanics of online commerce, the two can often be used interchangeably, there **is** a difference in what the terms represent. Ownership officially changes with a **purchase**; but not necessarily with an **order**.

***An** order* is the result of a performative verb ***to*** order. If I order you to shut the door (assuming all the [felicity conditions for ordering](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/felicityconditionsterm.htm) are true), then you have *an order* to shut the door -- but I do not **yet** have a shut door -- once again assuming the context is felicitous, I can expect to have it soon, but I don't have it yet.

In a commercial context, the customer *orders* (in the particular commercial sense) the merchant to deliver a product, in return for payment. The customer pledges the payment, and the merchant pledges the product, but this is still at the pledging stage; nothing needs to change hands in an order, except by pre-arranged convention. Both sides can expect the pledges to be redeemed in the future; but not yet.

*Purchase*, on the other hand -- a higher-register term for *buy* -- refers to the entire [Commercial Transaction Frame](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf). If I *purchase* something, then I have already paid for it, reserved it, and own it. It may or may not be in my physical possession -- it might be in for repair, or not delivered yet, or loaned to a museum -- but it's mine and I possess it already.

Answer (score 0):

They can generally be used interchangeably. I believe the preference is using purchase as a verb and order as a noun.

Interchangeable verb: "I am going to purchase|order some tea."

Interchangeable noun: "Thank you for your purchase|order."

Not interchangeable (noun vs verb):

"I would like to place an order for both black tea and green tea."

vs

"I would like to purchase both black tea and green tea."

"I would like to add items to my order."

vs

"I would like to purchase additional items."

To make things more confusing, there is a concept called "Purchase Order"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purchase_order